# Android: ThreadHandler

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application which requires calling multiple webservices to fetch data for the home screen. Shall I create a HandlerThread for processing requests in a single thread or should I create a seprate AsyncTask for each service request. Which of the approach is most efficient performance wise.

Comment: It totally depends on what type of tasks you need to do. Generally `AsyncTask` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to call webservices to fetch banner images and other settings and images as per user preference after he/she login to the app. Calling async task for each service will spawn a different thread if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for large amount of data i.e. for uploading and downloading and large operations use Thread and for simple operations which do not require large data use AsyncTask .